# How can I find a bounding box that encapsulates a specific point?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

```
[uppercaseName] => ATLANTA, GA
[description] => Atlanta, GA
[name] => Atlanta, GA
[_id] => MongoId Object (
)
[addedOn] => MongoDate Object (
    [sec] => 1318879015
    [usec] => 517000
)
[excludePoints] => Array (
)
[boundingBox] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [lon] => -84.516
        [lat] => 33.6747
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [lon] => -84.516
        [lat] => 33.8232
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [lon] => -84.2599
        [lat] => 33.8232
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [lon] => -84.2599
        [lat] => 33.6747
    )
)
```

That's my document (in MongoDB). I have several such documents and I want to run a query to find all documents that have a bounding box that encapsulates that specific Long and Lat. How would I do this?

Comment: just so i'm understanding this correctly; you have another box which you want to use to query mongo to find any other boxes that intersect your box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible with MongoDB.  MongoDB can index points and find all of the documents inside an area, but cannot index areas and query all of the documents containing an area that encloses a gives point.

There is a feature request for this:  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2874

Presently there is no scheduled date for this feature.  Please vote for it!

For more information on Geospatial Indexing and what it is capable of, please see the MongoDB documentation:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing